# On the Tensor product of spaces

Tags: tensor-products

Let $\Bbb F$ be real field.

Partition surface of a sphere $\Bbb S_n\in\Bbb F^n$ of radius $\sqrt{n}$ at an arbitrary center into $k$ equal divisions each holding $m=\frac{n}{k}$ orthonormal vectors (assume $k|n$). Call the partitions as $\Bbb S_n(j)$ for $j\in\{1,\dots,k\}$. Pick a complete set of $n$ orthonomal vectors and index them by $u_{i,j}$ where $j\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ refers to partition number and $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ refers to orthonormal vector in each partition.

How can one define a natural regular monomorphism $$f:\Bbb S_n(1)\otimes\dots\otimes\Bbb S_n(k)\subsetneq(\Bbb F^{n^{}})^{\otimes {k}}\rightarrow\Bbb S_{m}\otimes\dots\otimes\Bbb S_{m}\subsetneq(\Bbb F^{m})^{\otimes {k}}$$ such that $$u_{i,1}\otimes\dots\otimes u_{i,k} \perp u'_{i,1}\otimes\dots\otimes u'_{i,2}\implies f(u_{i,1}\otimes\dots\otimes u_{i,k}) \perp f(u'_{i,1}\otimes\dots\otimes u'_{i,2})?$$